# What are the "font settings theme" packages available in emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Is there any emacs package for **font** settings similar to **color-theme** for color. I am looking for a package which already has some good font settings and can be selected without restart of emacs

Comment: This question is more appropriate for superuser.com because it is not technically a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

(I agree with @lawlist that superuser.com might be a better site for this question.)

Here are two answers such packages:

- [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles), with command **`icicle-font`**.
- [***Do Re Mi***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/DoReMi), with command **`doremi-font+`** (also commands `doremi-font-size+`, `doremi-frame-font-size+`, and `doremi-buffer-font-size+`, which affect only the font size).

All of these commands let you choose a font interactively, seeing the effect immediately.  You can cycle among some or all of the available fonts.  With `icicle-font` you can type parts of the font name, to narrow the font choices, then cycle among that subset etc.

These are the quickest and friendliest ways I know of to choose a font -- either once and for all (e.g. customize Emacs so it uses that font by default) or to change on the fly.